# How to update the cookie in a request header?

Tags: python, http, cookies

I'm a newbie to python / web development and am working on a script logging in the google account with urllib2 and cookielib. Currently I get stuck by the 'Set-Cookie' staff.

In the very beginning, I'm using httplib to send request. When I post a login request, the response headers contain a dozen of 'Set-Cookie' entries like the following -

```
Set-Cookie: GAPS=1:HrRi-Z_IxwESn6DOHyY2qYkBFKK8_Q:csBfgQOtNDoeJhew;Path=/;Expires=Wed, 18-Sep-2013 07:27:34 GMT;Secure;HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: SID=DQAAAOcAAACx9rjyWTFqBgH2p8rHC7LS4C2yCfDcC8kW004wqkxteUf_EIJdzbXoz7Dy0w-60q0EFG57XTylnxmBBXhFR1YTpMrUyfYCBsZdPFKdyq471p6mQKC3nB-_XtuY-lol-WN3e6x8dz7mb20K6kPjefE3G9Y-
Set-Cookie: HSID=ALG231HZqMLBeBtwS;Domain=.google.com;Path=/;HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: SSID=Abl0p2GUu-XzSTN4m;Domain=.google.com;Path=/;Secure;HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: APISID=WVxc29cYqLxHKOyO/A0mu1KzvIbEwFM2WT;Domain=.google.com;Path=/
Set-Cookie: SAPISID=M4wLHhKLE_WvV-Cw/ALvXssXKb1oGTKxMk;Domain=.google.com;Path=/;Secure
```

After reading quite a few, I aware that these should be included in the next http request to let google know that the client cookie support is enabled. Thus I turned to urllib2 and cookielib. But the problem is that I don't find any method to update the 'Set-Cookie's in my requests. Do you happen to if there's a way to update the cookies according to the server responses, which is easier than handle the raw strings from scratch?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Kai

Answer (score -1):

[Here](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/cookielib.shtml) you can find an example on how to do this. The idea is to have a cookie jar storing all the collected cookies. The jar gets used by urllib2's opener. I hope this helps.